# Maximum number of processes in linux

Tags: linux, process, operating-system

What is the maximum limit to the number of processes possible in a linux system? How can we find it ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 47):

Your kernel should export this information in `procfs`:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
```

This is the maximum number of unique process identifiers your system can support.

Since it is a file, `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` can be inspected from any capable programming language.

Comment: this may be true, but in most nice distros this is limited by /etc/security/limits.conf which can filter max number of processes on user/group/domain basis.

Comment: `ulimit` might limit the max per-user processes to less than the maximum pid, and from a bit of Googling, there's other limitations in play as well (but I couldn't find any definitive sources to confirm, such as LKML or a well known Dev posting it).

Comment: `int fd = read("/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max");` is not valid, nor is it valid for any other file.

Comment: @immibis I edited out the bogus C; hopefully my edit will be approved soon.

Answer (score 20):

> sysctl kernel.pid_max

or

> cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max

As suggested by Ninefingers.

For completeness, you can change it temporarily by writing to /proc/syskernel/pid_max or permanently by adding:

> kernel.pid_max = 4194303

to /etc/sysctl.conf. 4194303 is the maximum limit for x86_64 and 32767 for x86.

Comment: just tried `sysctl kernel.pid_max=4194304` and it succeeded (Linux 3.10.25)

Comment: @zed_0xff as long as you are aware that the change is not persistent it's all good!

Comment: `printf '%x\n' 4194303` gives `3fffff`

Comment: The actual maximum is 32768 on 32 bit kernels, and 4194304 on 64 bit.  However the maximum PID you will see is 1 less.  See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/162105/23450

Answer (score 16):

Short answer to your question : Number of process possible in the linux system is **UNLIMITED**.

But there is a limit on number of process per user(except root who has no limit).

And you can check your user limits with below command (apposite to "max user processes").

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 256447
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 128000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 500000
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

If you want to increase the limit on number of process for a particular user(for eg: hadoop ) , you need to make below entry in  **/etc/security/limits.conf**

```
hadoop - nproc 500000
```

Comment: Sometimes above change requires a restart to get the change in effect.

Comment: This begs a citation for the number is 'unlimited', for ulimit means it doesn't have a limit set (unlimited), but the number of processes the scheduler is allowed isn't unlimited ... as in infinite.

The ulimit wasn't the question.

Comment: the kernel has a hard limit of 4mln I think

Comment: It can't be unlimited since last but not least the hardware imposes limits.

Answer (score 5):

`kernel.pid_max` is a limiting factor, but at least as important is `kernel.threads-max`. It's worth noting that the default nproc ulimit for each user is `kernel.threads-max` divided by two, and that every thread counts toward a user's nproc limit. Thus, `ps -u $USER` may make it appear that a user has not exhausted their nproc limit, but `ps -L -u $USER` could tell a very different story.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean that a mongodb process can only create with `max nproc = threads-max / 2` ?

Because i'm trying to increase nproc as unlimited.

I tried to put limits on `/etc/security/limits.conf` as like this:

`mongodb       soft        nproc      unlimited
mongodb       hard      nproc        unlimited
mongodb       soft       nofile      50000
mongodb       hard      nofile      50000
mongodb soft    sigpending      unlimited
mongodb hard    sigpending      unlimited`

However it didn'r reflect on mongodb process even after complete reboot.

Then i tried to put `ulimit -u unlimited` command to `/etc/init.d/mongodb` but after i tried to start with this file i got

`/etc/init.d/mongodb: 67: ulimit: Illegal option -u`

error. Is this `kernel.threads-max` is limiting mongodb max process count?