# how many processes can be created with python os.fork()

Tags: python, fork

If I do this below:

```
for i in range(10000):
    os.fork()
```

What's going on? don't consider reaping.. I just wanna know about os.fork() can make how much processes in linux, if it 's just like windows, only can make about 2000 processes, how the next 8000 processes will do?
Thanks.

Comment: `os.fork` creates a new process.  To be pedantic, that new process includes one new thread, so a new thread is indeed created, but this is probably not what you mean.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: The same number as POSIX fork. Your question is not about python, but rather POSIX/Linux.

Comment: @msw  I have maybe ten thousands virtual machines, I want to ssh every machine and then do something , so I use os.fork to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.fork()` spawns a new OS-level process. Any limits on the number of those aren't dependent on Python, but on the operating system. According to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361816/maximum-number-of-processes-in-linux), on Linux you can find out about any software-imposed constraints on that by looking at:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
```

but that might be further restrained by `/etc/security/limits.conf`. If those don't hit you first, you will eventually run into problems with available hardware resources - your code is a [fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb), and type of trivial denial of service attack (any software limits on the number of processes are set to *avoid* this kind of attack).

Comment: there's also `ulimit -u`

Comment: @lvc I understand it now, for instance ,my cpu,mem or any other limits only can support 2000 threads,how does the rest do? what bad things will happen?

Comment: @lvc Looks like I need a better idea.I find a way, I will divided into many groups of my 10,000 virtual machines.

Answer (score 2):

The code doesn't do what you think it does.

When you're forking, you're actually *duplicating* the current process.

This means that after forking, *both* processes will continue the iteration from the same point. And then both will fork, and so on... The number of created threads will be *exponential*.

Example:

```
import os
for i in range(3):
    os.fork();

print "T"
```

When executed, you should see 2^3 = 8 processes.

Just to return to your original question, since `fork` creates processes, the limit on the number of threads is irrelevant.

Comment: .In my code, during the loop ,if os.fork ,it will continue, otherwise,it will do something. so it should work well. but the effect you point out, it's indeed interesting,i didn't notice it before

Answer (score 1):

The [`os.fork()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fork) function creates a copy of the calling process. Threads are created in Python by using the [`threading`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module.

The amount of processes you can create on a UNIX-like system such as Linux is generally limited by the amount of memory the computer has and certain limits set in the operating system. The output of the command `ulimit -a` shows all the limits.

The amount of *threads* you can create within a process is usually limited by the amount of stack space that the process has and the maximal amount of (virtua)l memory that the process is allowed to have. These limits are also shown by `ulimit`.

Note that when you are using the standard python implementation (a.k.a CPython), only *one* thread at a time can be executing Python bytecode.