# Can I reuse (ephemeral) ports connecting to different hosts?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

Can and will an operating system reuse a source port number for a connection to a different destination address/port combination?

If I `connect()` to enough hosts, and keep those connections open, eventually I'll run out of unique source ports, exhausting the ephemeral range, the non-root range (1025-65,535; assuming non-root) or the absolute range (0-65,535).  I want to know if those represent real limits to the number of hosts I can simultaneously have a connection to.  I'm interested in what the standards promise (or don't), as well as the reality on Linux (Windows would be a bonus).

I know that opening that many connections will likely run into a number of other limits; that's a different issue and question.  If it matters, this massive number of connections would be divided among a similarly large number of processes.  I'm interested in the case where I'm requesting an ephemeral port, not manually `bind()`ing one.  If under "normal" circumstances ports won't be reused, are there ways of changing that behavior from user-space (at which point `bind()`ing to a specific point becomes an option)?

Comment: If you're going to have roughly the same number of processes as you do connections, try (under Linux) doing the shell command `ps -ef`.  You'll find that the process numbers range from 1 to 32767 or so.  You'll run out of processes way sooner than you run out of ephemeral ports.

Comment: Why should a process only open a single port? It's easy for a process to keep 1000s of connections open, servers like nginx do it all the time and even browsers often have multiple connections open.

Comment: @Steffen: There is no reason a process should open only a single port.  I was concerned, though, about OP's statement: "If it matters, this massive number of connections would be divided among a similarly large number of processes."

Comment: @Bill: max_pid is adjustable on Linux: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12152304/16672  I intended for such things to fall until "will likely run into a number of other limits," but I wasn't clear.

Comment: @Steffen and Bill: I certainly appreciate that this may be a terrible idea for a host of reasons.  To paraphrase Donald Rumseld, you go to war with the code you have, not the code you might want or wish to have at a later time.

Comment: There's a delightfully apropos ambiguity here.  In reference to the code you're using, does "go to war with" mean "go to war using", or does it mean "go to war against"?  ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the kernel will not reuse any in-use port for an ephemeral port, which may result in failures if you have 64K+ simultaneous ports in use.

You can explicitly reuse a port by using the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option and explicitly binding to the same port.  This only works if none of the ports are listening (you can't reuse a listening port), and if you connect each socket to a different remote address.

Comment: And this works because the combination that must be unique is 'source IP address:source port:destination IP address:destination port' for a completed connection, but listeners must be unique based on 'listening IP address:listening port' only.

Comment: How does it know in advance that you're going to connect to a different address?

Comment: @EJP: it doesn't.  If you use REUSEADDR to bind the same port then attempt to connect to the same address, the connect will fail.  This is a corner case that probably isn't well tested, so I wouldn't be suprised if doing this had other bad effects, such as crashing the machine...

Comment: Yep I just tested it myself on Windows 2k, it works as you describe, but no crash. My answer dates from about 1983 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In theory yes. In practice no, because bind precedes connect, and so it can't see what you're connecting to, so can't see that the 4-tuple would be unique, so won't let you reuse an ephemeral port.

Comment: Are you referring to the bind that the kernel and/or C library is doing as part of my connect() call?  If I don't explicitly bind() prior to connect(), it seems like kernel/library has the information it needs.  Of course there may be good reasons to not be that clever and to behave as though I'd called bind().

Comment: @AlanDeSmet If the bind() is implicit, as part of connect(), it isn't reusing anything. It finds a free port. The only way you can reuse any port at any time is via an explicit bind().