# maximum number of processes and maximum PID value

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, pid

Referring to this question [maximum-number-of-processes-in-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361816/maximum-number-of-processes-in-linux)

I under stand that **kernel.pid**_max affects the maximum value for PID and **max user processes** in **/etc/security/limits.conf** file affects total number of processes for each user.

so if this is the right information, if for example **pid_max** is 10 and **max user process** is 30609. I think that Kernel will limit no of processes to 10 because there is no more available PIDs.

NOTE : the example is for understanding only

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but threads may also count as processes, so it's really an upper limit.

Comment: You mean that each process still have capability to start 30609 threads. If so this number representing max number of process per user and maximum number of threads per process

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you, do you mean kernel.threads-max?