# maximum concurrent processes active on a system at a time with fork()

Tags: c, fork

this program is used to create maximum no. of processes system is allowed to create

Ok fine but i didn't get the else part what is going in there

When i execute it my system hangs boot itself automatically??

Can someone please explain it how the following code works??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int i = 1;

    for(;;)
    {
        pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0)
            printf("MAX no of concurrent process are %d\n",i);

        if(pid == 0)
            i++;
        else
        {
            wait(0);
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the else part will only run on parent process. hence, it wait()s for its children to exit.

Comment: yes it is but what about the exit() after the wait() statement?

Comment: @IsaA how come parent call exit()?

Comment: A semantic parser would issue a "warning: unreachable code" statement. ;-)

Comment: Should be `if(pid<0) { printf("..."); exit(0); }`

Comment: @user3386109 can you tell how the program will work with what you have just said??

Comment: I am referring to Book The 'C' Odessey UNIX

Comment: The problem that I see is that the posted code uses all available processes, and then after the `fork` fails, it calls `wait(0)` on a process that has no children.  So I expect that `wait` will never return, and the system will crash since it can't create more processes.

Comment: @user3386109 when fork is called first time child process will increment i and the parent process will call the else part i.e it will wait for child process to exit and then call exit() itself. I dont't get it why would parent process wait for child who doesn't call exit and then exit itself. can you please elaborate your answer

Comment: Yes, but what happens when the `fork` fails and returns a value that's less than 0?  You call `printf`, and then what?

Comment: @user3386109 i really want to know why would parent process wait for the child process which doesn't even call exit ?

Comment: @user3386109 ok i get it but my system hangs after few seconds and reboot itself the if(pid<0) part never get called

Comment: Yes, running a ***[fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb)*** on your system is a bad way to determine the process limit. Even with the change I suggested, it's still possible that your system will crash before displaying the `printf`. There are better ways to determine the process limit. See ***[this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361816/maximum-number-of-processes-in-linux)*** for example.

Comment: @user3386109 This is not really a fork bomb: it only creates *one* child process per child (no exponential increase) and is supposed to stop once an error occurs.

Comment: On failure of any [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), notably [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), you should use  `errno`, e.g. with [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html)

Comment: the fork failure part never make it system runs out of memory before and reboot itself

Answer (score 1):

On entering the `for` loop, the process is tried to be forked.

On success, in the parent process, `fork()` returns something `> 0`, the PID of the child. The child returns `0`.

On failure, `fork()` returns `< 0`. This case should be handled appropriately.

In your code, the child process increments the "inherited" `i` and goes on with the next loop run, but the parent waits for its child and exits.

This all goes well up to the point where `fork()` fails. Then you get an output, but the code is continued nevertheless, up to `wait(0)`. There it hangs, and so do all its parents.

If you would do

```
if(pid < 0) {
    printf("MAX no of concurrent process are %d\n",i);
    exit(0); // or return 0
}
```

the child which was unable to create another child would exit properly and so would do all of its parents.

Comment: the if(pid < 0) doesn't matter it will never going to execute the system will run out of memory before and hang itself till death