# Create a program to calculate the maximum number of processes in the system

Tags: c, fork, child-process

I have the following code, which I'm trying to calculate all process. I do not understand how to calculate the maximum number of process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
   int pid, pidmax = 0;
   while(1) 
   {
       pid = fork();
       pidmax = getpid();
       if(pid == 0){
           if(pidmax < getpid())
               pidmax = getpid();
           printf("pid: %d, max: %d\n", getpid(), pidmax);  
           return 0;
       }

       if(pid == -1) {
        printf("Maximum process: %d\n", pidmax);
        exit(-1);
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you can do it by using a counter, increment the counter while got a fork.

Comment: It works, but need to find the maximum number using only a comparison of their id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are much easier ways to do this rather than via experimentation.

Most Unix systems provide [`ulimit`](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) to show you the various soft (ie. user defined) and hard (ie. admin defined) limits on your account. For example, here's my soft and hard limits on OS X.

```
$ ulimit -a -S
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 709
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited

$ ulimit -a -H
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) unlimited
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 65532
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1064
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

While the system may support more processes, your program will be limited by these limits. I am limited to 709 (what an odd number) processes and can raise it to 1064.

The maximum number of processes at a single time is limited by the size of `pid_t` and often by a restriction defined in the kernel. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361816/maximum-number-of-processes-in-linux) and also [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16883/what-is-the-maximum-value-of-the-process-id#16884) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

This can be possible by counting number of numbered directories present inside `/proc` directory. These numbered directories are the PID's of processes which are currently running.

`/proc` referred to as a process information pseudo-file system.
For more information, you can visit,
http://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html

I have written small code which gives number of processes running.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main()
{
        DIR* proc = opendir("/proc");
        struct dirent* ent;
        int count = 0;

        if(proc == NULL) {
                perror("opendir(/proc)");
                return 1;
        }       

        while(ent = readdir(proc)) {
            if(!isdigit(*ent->d_name))
                continue;
            count++; //if directory name is number then increment the count.
        }

        closedir(proc);

        printf("Number of Processes=%d\n",count);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: At least leave a comment for the down vote ..  Don't just down vote ...

Comment: @A. Norvag ... You can try my solution. It will work for you. Revert in case of any query...

Comment: I tried your solution. But it gives not the result I want. With this code it turned only 3 of the process, even though the maximum number of processes in the system: 32765

Comment: Note that not all Unix systems provide [procfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs). For example, OS X does not have it. Instead you use `sysctl`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for proc(5), and you'll see this for the processes field:

```
Number of forks since boot.
```

So it's simply not the number you're looking for. ps will give you that as you already know, **counting the directories with only numbers in their name under /proc is another approach.**

**`ulimit`** might limit the max per-user processes to less than the maximum pid.

ulimit -u which says the total processes a user can have at a particular time. The above command returns me the output as 63203. This means for all the processes that a user has created at a point of time the user can have 63203 processes running.

You will get total number of running processes on a given machine

```
 ps -e | wc -l
```