# MongoDB: soft rlimits too low. rlimits set to 27774 processes, 64000 files. Number of processes should be at least 32000 : 0.5 times number of files

Tags: mongodb, ulimit

I have an Ubuntu server which is running on 14.04.05 LTS.

There are several applications that is ugins mongodb installed also on this server. MongoDB version is 3.4.2

I'm trying to increase max process ulimit of mongodb process.

I first put these lines to `/etc/security/limits.conf`

`*       soft        nproc      unlimited
*       hard      nproc        unlimited
*       soft       nofile      64000
*       hard      nofile      64000
*       soft    sigpending      unlimited
*       hard    sigpending      unlimited
root       soft        nproc        unlimited
root       hard      nproc        unlimited
root       soft       nofile      64000
root       hard      nofile      64000
root    soft    sigpending      unlimited
root    hard    sigpending      unlimited
mongodb       soft        nproc      unlimited
mongodb       hard      nproc        unlimited
mongodb       soft       nofile      64000
mongodb       hard      nofile      64000
mongodb soft    sigpending      unlimited
mongodb hard    sigpending      unlimited`

and also put required pam.limits to proper locations and reboot but no success.

Then i tried to manually run `ulimit -u unlimited` command which is reflected immediately after i executed it (i seen the result with `ulimit -a` command). And then reboot the mongodb process but the limits are didn't changed.

Then i tried to put these lines to:

`ulimit -f unlimited
ulimit -t unlimited
ulimit -v unlimited
ulimit -n 64000
ulimit -m unlimited
ulimit -u unlimited`

to `/etc/init.d/mongodb` file and try to start mongodb process with `/etc/init.d/mongodb start` but i got this error:

`/etc/init.d/mongodb: 67: ulimit: Illegal option -u`

I also put this line `mongod     soft    nproc     64000` to `/etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf` and tried to reboot but no success.

On this thread `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361816/maximum-number-of-processes-in-linux` i saw that one user reported about `kernel.threads-max` is limiting this number but on my another server i can get more max connection limit then `kernel.threads-max / 2`

So I'm not sure where do i doing wrong but any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Adding "@" to the lines is working for me:

```
@mongodb       soft        nproc      unlimited
@mongodb       hard      nproc        unlimited
@mongodb       soft       nofile      64000
@mongodb       hard      nofile      64000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding -S to each line, like this:
    ulimit -S -n 4096

Answer (score 0):

For the change to be persistent you have to edit de init script, for example, in Red Hat 7, the init script has the following line:

```
LimitNOFILE=64000
```

You have to add the next one:

```
LimitNPROC=32000
```

Then restart the service.

I hope this helps.