# Max number of threads that can run on unix a machine

Tags: multithreading, unix, hardware

I have below configuration of a unix machine:

**Command :**

```
lscpu | grep -E '^Thread|^Core|^Socket|^CPU\('
```

**Result :**

```
CPUs :               8
Thread(s) per core : 8
Core(s) per socket : 1
Socket(s)          : 1
```

My understanding is:

**Max. number of threads that can run on this machine  = Sockets X Cores per Socket X Thread(s) per Core**

Or

**Max. number of threads that can run on this machine  = CPUs**

Is this understanding correct?

or

Is there different formulae to decide maximum number of threads that can run on a machine?

**EDIT**

I meant max. number of threads that can run in parallel.

e.g. by starting n number of threadpools etc.

For increasing performance of my application I want to run it on max. number of threads, can it be determined by above parameters?

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344203/maximum-number-of-threads-per-process-in-linux and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361816/maximum-number-of-processes-in-linux. Also by *running* do you mean *running in parallel*? Or the maximum that can be present?

Comment: @Allan yes I mean running in parallel, So parameters which I have mentioned have any relation in deciding max. number of threads than can run in parallel.